# Remap key in Win 8.1 to a shortcut

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, button-remapping

I would like to remap a keyboard key in Win 8.1 to a shortcut...does anyone know how to do this? Specifically I would like to remap the key that has a picture of a file (located between the Alt and Ctrl keys) to "Win+M". In other words I would like to minimize all windows when I press this button.

Answer (score 0):

Shure there are many ways to do Key-Remaping  on Windows - But non of them will help You witch your Problem. Why? Simply cause you will Assign Windows + M to the Windows Key.

For any other Shortcut or Key Remapping, please first Google it there are many Applications and How-to's e.g. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14249/create-custom-windows-key-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows/